# Ranked tag recommendation for university courses

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Our system allows an admin to manage a database of university courses. These courses have multiple fields, like the department, a title, and a description.

I am adding the ability to add learning objectives to a course. To simplify the problem, let's say that learning objectives are just tags. Courses can have more than one learning objective associated with them. So a course like CHEM 101 might have "chemistry", "technology", "science", and several others.

Assuming I can reduce a course to a set of features, (using keywords/stemming/nlp, I suppose?), what kind of problem is this and what algorithm would you suggest? It seems very similar to a classification problem, but I want to provide a sorted list of suggestions with the most relevant at the top.

Comment: What is the sort criteria? it's not clear. You say "most relevant" but to what?

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely turn out to be multiple binary classification problems.

Instead of building just one classifier, you would have to build as many classifiers as there are tags. Each classifier's task would be to predict whether a certain tag exists or not. A tag specific probability threshold can then be learnt by tuning over the precision-curve where course wise precision recall can be calculated.

The percentile of the predicted probability for each tag can be used to obtain a ordered (sorted) list of tag suggestions.

This way of converting a multi-class problem to multiple binary classification problems is known as binary relevance. While it is very efficient, it assumes that the labels themselves are independent. However, picking the probability threshold for each tag in order to optimize the course wise precision recall curve can lead to modeling dependence in the tags.